# No qmake option found in qt quick application

Tags: python, qt, cmake, qt-creator, qmake

i have to create a qt project for qml and python (i'm new at this), i saw in various tutorials that when creating a qt quick application, i should select qmake as builder for the project, but it won't show up, i have it installed because with a qt widgets application qmake pops up. Any ideas?

Qt creator community 10.0.0 (Open source version)

Windows 11

I tried re installing qt creator and checking with the maintenance tool to see if qmake was there, and it was. Even the example programs are generated with Cmake and not qmake, i can't find it in the build options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to these Qt Creator bug reports [qmake option missing from Application wizard](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-28964)
 and [Qt Quick build system doesn't have qmake option](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-28990)
 disabling qmake from `Application wizard` was intentional in `Qt Creator 10.0` to boost transition to CMake. This does not imply that qmake is not supported in Qt Creator anymore, you can still open qmake projects.

However, because of the customer feedback Application Wizard qmake support will be brought back in `Qt Creator 10.0.1` with this fix: https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt-creator/qt-creator/+/473719, estimated to be released in early May.

Meanwhile, you can create a pro file manually and open it with Qt Creator: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-tutorial.html

Comment: 10.0.2 here and it is still missing. Shame on Qt for being so obtrusive...